# Certificate issue causing code to fail

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl-certificate, certificate

We have some code that connects to a website to call a web service. When I run the code on our server under my account (local admin) the code runs fine. When I run the code under a different user the code fails and complains that it can not connect.

The certificate to connect to the web service is stored under Computer in the certificate store. When I browse the store as admin I see it and when I browse as the non admin account I can not see computer area.

Is there a way to install a certificate for all users on the system?

Answer (score 2):

While logged on as an administrator:

- open MMC -> Certificates -> Machine.
- Right-click on the certificate > All Tasks > Manage Private Keys
- Add the Authenticated Users security principal with the required permissions.

[image]

More information:

The certificate has a corresponding file located at:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

If you need to deploy this to multiple computers, you would need to determine which file corresponded to your certificate.  Refer to the following for more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1271530/175990